# C++ weirdness with array initialization from brace-enclosed lists

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, enumeration

I can't get the code below to compile with either GCC or Clang. Tried both C++11 and C++14.

My question:
Is there any logical reason for this not to be implemented? Myself, I can't think of any... See below for my workaround.

```
enum class fruit {
    APPLES,
    ORANGES,
    STRAWBERRIES
};
struct Area {float x, y, width, height;};
const Area test[] = {
    [fruit::APPLES] = {1,2,3,4},
    [fruit::ORANGES] = {2,2,3,4},
    [fruit::STRAWBERRIES] = {3,2,3,4}
};
```

This though will compile just fine:

```
namespace fruit { // instead of enum class, this works
    enum {
            APPLES,
            ORANGES,
            STRAWBERRIES
    };
}
struct Area {float x, y, width, height;};
const Area test[] = {
    [fruit::APPLES] = {1,2,3,4},
    [fruit::ORANGES] = {2,2,3,4},
    [fruit::STRAWBERRIES] = {3,2,3,4}
};
```

Comment: an `enum class` is not implicitly convertible to an integral value, which is the exact purpose of a `enum class`.

Comment: As @Jack said, it's intentionally not implicitly convertible, you can explicitly cast it though.

Comment: Your version that "compiles fine" isn't valid C++ either.

Comment: @juanchopanza Care to explain?

Comment: It compiles using the online C++ shell found here though: http://cpp.sh But I think that is because of an outdated GCC version they use.

Comment: It uses a C99 feature which isn't part of C++.

Comment: Designated initializers are a feature of C that GCC provides as an extension when compiling C++ code.  They are not part of C++.  Clang provides a similar extension along with a warning, and MSVC has no support for them.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry for my ignoranse, but which feature is that? I don't want to write code not following the standards, so it would be useful for me to know exactly what you mean so I can stop doing it.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Thanks for explaining that! No warnings ever showed here though.

Comment: Yes, I can't actually find a GCC flag that will enable a warning for this extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Okay, so I will answer this myself from what I learned in the comments.

This is apparently called using "designated initializer" and it's a C99 feature, not a part of the C++ standard (even if it compiles in some cases):

```
int array[] = {
    [1] = 11,
    [0] = 22
};
```

The code in my question compiles for me if I make these changes though:

```
[fruit::APPLES] = {1,2,3,4}
```

Change into:

```
[(int)fruit::APPLES] = {1,2,3,4}
```

Or into (the more correct way):

```
[static_cast<int>(fruit::APPLES)] = {1,2,3,4}
```

But if you want to be standard compatible it's best not to use designated initializers and instead rewrite the code...